# PostgreSQL to JSON object

Tags: json, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have a table named info that has columns like so:

```
kod_id, region
```

I need to get a JSON response like this:

```
"List of regions": [
            {
                "Region name": "Moscow region",
                "Region Code": "77"
            },
            {
                "Region Name": "Belgorod Oblast",
                "Region Code": "31"
            },
            {
                "Region Name": "Bryansk Oblast",
                "Region Code": "32"
            },
            {
                "Region Name": "Vladimir Oblast", 
                "Region Code": "33"  
            }
        ]
```

I wrote a query of the form:

```sql
SELECT json_build_object( 'List of regions'
                         ,json_build_array( 'Region name', "region"
                                           ,'Region code', "kod_id") )
FROM "regions";
```

and got the output:

```
{ "List of regions" : ["Region name", "Republic of Bashkortostan", "Region code", " 02"]}
{ "List of regions" : ["Region Name", "Republic of Buryatia", "Region Code", "03"]}
{ "List of Regions" : ["Region Name", "Republic of Altai", "Region Code", "04"]}
{ "List of Regions" : ["Region Name", "Republic of Dagestan", "Region Code", "05"]}
{ "List of Regions" : ["Region Name", "Republic of Ingushetia", "Region Code", "06"]}
{ "List of Regions" : ["Region Name", "Kabardino-Balkarian Republic", "Region Code", "07"]}
```

Why do I get the wrong result?

Comment: Output is good, Could you share the input data too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this data :

```
create table regions (
  region varchar(20),
  kod_id int
);

insert into regions values
('Moscow region', 77),
('Belgorod Oblast', 31),
('Bryansk Oblast', 32),
('Vladimir Oblast', 33);
```

You will need to aggregates JSON objects built by `json_build_object`, as a JSON array using `json_agg` :

```
SELECT json_build_object('List of regions',
                            json_agg(
                               json_build_object ('Region name', region, 'region code', kod_id)
                            )
                        )
FROM regions;
```

Result :

```
{
   "List of regions":[
      {
         "Region name":"Moscow region",
         "region code":77
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Belgorod Oblast",
         "region code":31
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Bryansk Oblast",
         "region code":32
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Vladimir Oblast",
         "region code":33
      }
   ]
}
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-aVq67vc)

Comment: Big thanks! That's what I need.

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)