# Merge two postgres outputs into a single output

Tags: json, postgresql

I have  two tables in postgres
regions
'Passenger transportation'

regions:
code_id, region

'Passenger transportation':
"Total thousands of people", "Unit of measure",
"Date of report", "transport",
"Railway transport", "Air transport",
"sea transport", "Inland sea transport"

I have two query in postgres:
1:

```
SELECT json_build_object('Passenger transportation',
json_agg(
json_build_object ('Total thousands of people', "Total thousands of people", 'Unit of measure', "Unit of measure",
'Date of report', "Date of report", 'transport', "transport",
'Railway transport', "Railway transport", 'Air transport', "Air transport",
'sea transport', "sea transport", 'Inland sea transport', "Inland sea transport"
)
)
)
FROM "1.0"
```

and 2:

```
SELECT json_build_object('List of regions',
                            json_agg(
                               json_build_object ('Region name', region, 'region code', kod_id)
                            )
                        )
FROM regions;
```

Their's outputs what I have

1:

```
{
  "Passenger transportation": [
    {
      "Total thousands of people": 17565,
      "Unit of measure": "Thousands of people",
      "Date of report": "2023-06-01",
      "transport": 2423,
      "Railway transport": 421,
      "Air transport": 234,
      "sea transport": 54,
      "Inland sea transport": 23
    }
 ]
}
```

2:

```
[
{
   "List of regions":[
      {
         "Region name":"Moscow region",
         "region code":77
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Belgorod Oblast",
         "region code":31
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Bryansk Oblast",
         "region code":32
      }
   ]
}
```

**I need to get a json response like this:**

```
{
   "List of regions":[
      {
         "Region name":"Moscow region",
         "region code":77
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Belgorod Oblast",
         "region code":31
      }
   ]
,
{
  "Passenger transportation": [
    {
      "Total thousands of people": 17565,
      "Unit of measure": "Thousands of people",
      "Date of report": "2023-06-01",
      "transport": 2423,
      "Railway transport": 423,
      "Air transport": 234,
      "sea transport": 54,
      "Inland sea transport": 23
    }
}
```

```
{
   "List of regions":[
      {
         "Region name":"Moscow region",
         "region code":77
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Belgorod Oblast",
         "region code":31
      }
   ]
,
{
  "Passenger transportation": [
    {
      "Total thousands of people": 17566,
      "Unit of measure": "Thousands of people",
      "Date of report": "2023-06-02",
      "transport": 2425,
      "Railway transport": 423,
      "Air transport": 554,
      "sea transport": 55,
      "Inland sea transport": 13
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me how to get the output I want?

Maybe who's know where I can see sample queries in postgres for json output?

Comment: Is there any column linking those two tables ?

Comment: There is no such column.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the operator `||` to concatenate two jsonb values into a new jsonb value :

```
WITH regions_cte as (
  SELECT json_build_object('List of regions',
                         json_agg(
                             json_build_object ('Region name', region, 'region code', kod_id)
                         )
                        ) as regions
  FROM regions
),
passengers_cte as (
  SELECT json_build_object('Passenger transportation',
                           json_agg(
                              json_build_object ('Total thousands of people', "Total thousands of people", 'Unit of measure', "Unit of measure",
                                'Date of report', "Date of report", 'transport', "transport",
                                'Railway transport', "Railway transport", 'Air transport', "Air transport",
                                'sea transport', "sea transport", 'Inland sea transport', "Inland sea transport"
                              )
                           )
        ) as passengers
  FROM Passenger_transportation
)
select regions::jsonb || passengers::jsonb
from regions_cte, passengers_cte;
```

If we take this data :

```
create table regions (
  region varchar(20),
  kod_id int
);

insert into regions values
('Moscow region', 77), ('Belgorod Oblast', 31), ('Bryansk Oblast', 32), ('Vladimir Oblast', 33);

create table Passenger_transportation (
      "Total thousands of people" int,
      "Unit of measure" varchar(20),
      "Date of report" date,
      "transport" int,
      "Railway transport" int,
      "Air transport" int,
      "sea transport" int,
      "Inland sea transport" int
);

insert into Passenger_transportation values
(17565, 'Thousands of people', '2023-06-01', 2423, 421, 234, 54, 23);
```

We will get as result :

```
{
   "List of regions":[
      {
         "Region name":"Moscow region",
         "region code":77
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Belgorod Oblast",
         "region code":31
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Bryansk Oblast",
         "region code":32
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Vladimir Oblast",
         "region code":33
      }
   ],
   "Passenger transportation":[
      {
         "transport":2423,
         "Air transport":234,
         "sea transport":54,
         "Date of report":"2023-06-01",
         "Unit of measure":"Thousands of people",
         "Railway transport":421,
         "Inland sea transport":23,
         "Total thousands of people":17565
      }
   ]
}
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pjyhNXq9)

This question is a follow-up of this one : [PostgreSQL to JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77535367/postgresql-to-json-object)

Comment: Big thanks for answer! But if I have several rows filled in the table "Passenger_transportation", 
I get this output
 {
   "List of regions":[
      {
         "Region name":"Moscow region",
         "region code":77
      },
      {
         "Region name":"Belgorod Oblast",
         "region code":31
      }
   ]
 "Passenger transportation":[
      {
         "transport":2423,
         "Air transport":234,
         "sea transport":54,
},
     {
         "transport":2424,
         "Air transport":235,
         "sea transport":56,
      }
   ]
}

Comment: There should be a link between those tables !, you can have a column in table **Passenger_transportation** reference table **regions**  Exemple https://dbfiddle.uk/ZLyjhgft